# JAVA Project...want to add a .java file into my project

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to add a .java file into my project. But this .java has "Main". and this is a big .java file. 
I just want to call and run this .java file somewhere in my project. How can I deal with this?
Wish I made this clear.
Thanks you all.

P.s. I m using netbeans.

With IDE, Netbeans

Comment: How do you build your project (with ant/maven/IDE) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the file to your project like any other Java source file. After Netbeans has compiled it successfully, you can call the code with:

```
String[] args = { "arg1", "arg2" };
Main.main(args); // Call of static method main()
```

(where "Main" is the name of the class which is contained in your .java file).

Answer (score 1):

you should check a simple helloworld tutorial such as this one:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html

jason